# BestObjectiveBound vs. ObjectiveValue

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

My model minimizes objective function and finishes within max_time_in_seconds, at ObjectiveValue higher than BestObjectiveBound.

```
solution.BestObjectiveBound()
Out[1]: -73000.0

solution.ObjectiveValue()
Out[2]: -71000.0
```

---

According to [CP model reference](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.py#L2258), BestObjectiveBound

```
Returns the best lower (upper) bound found when min(max)imizing.
```

Does it mean CP-SAT found a better solution but still submitted the one with higher objective value?

Or, is BestObjectiveBound merely a [shifted ObjectiveValue](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/sat_parameters.proto) (How is the offset determined?)?

```
// Stop the search when the gap between the best feasible objective (O) and
// our best objective bound (B) is smaller than a limit.
// The exact definition is:
// - Absolute: abs(O - B)
// - Relative: abs(O - B) / max(1, abs(O)).
//
// Important: The relative gap depends on the objective offset! If you
// artificially shift the objective, you will get widely different value of
// the relative gap.
```

Comment: The *solver proved* that there is *no better = smaller solution possible* than `-73000 = BestObjectiveBound`. It found a *feasible solution* (primal solution) with `-71000 = ObjectiveValue`. *As of yet, the solver does not know* if `-71000` is *optimal* or  if there is another solution in `[-73000, -71000)` (while he doesn't care about those in `[-70999, +inf)`). Due to the time-limit, the solver stops and won't try to resolve this non-knowledge. (The solver will always return the best solution (or one of those when there are ties) if he found one.)

Comment: @sascha ah, so BestObjectiveBound is just the highest possible achievable value and if there was no time limit, solver could still conclude that objective value of -71000 is optimal in spite of theoretically calculated but practically unachievable value of -73000?

Comment: No quite. There might be a practical solution of `objective = -73000`. The thing is: you got this **lower-bound** (proven that there is no better one) and you obtained an **upper-bound**, an **available feasible solution** with `objective = -71000` (and you are not interested in worse ones). Everything in-between is **unknown**. -71000 might be optimal, -73000 might be optimal. -71213 might be optimal. We don't know. Without a time-limit, every *complete solver* (which or-tools cp-sat is) will conclude the final truth at some point (but this might be often way too slow: NP-hardness and so on).

Comment: This lower-bound is not necessarily a *dumb* bound created from the start. It *evolves* over time using multiple techniques (and it's actually very hard to infer lower-bounds; in contrast to upper-bounds: any solution found by pure luck gives you an upper-bound -> *there exists ...*; a lower-bound on the other hand means *proving the absence of solutions in some range* -> *there does not exist ... / for all ... is infeasible*).

Comment: @sascha Excellent answer, I will mediate upon this answer. This could be submitted as a repl\.